# PHP Date Always show expired

Tags: php

`$current_season_expiry` value is `"2016-07-23"`, though the date is not passed yet, regardless of any date it shows "expired". I am comparing $current_season_expiry with today's date.

```
echo $current_season_expiry;
if( $current_season_expiry >= date("Ymd") ) {
    echo "is not expired";
}else{
    echo "expired";
}
```

Comment: `2016-07-23` and `Ymd` are not the same format. So don't even bother about that format, just compare the timestamps of the two dates.

Comment: You're comparing Y-m-d to Ymd, the `-` characters are what's causing the problem. If you compare dates as strings, make sure the formats match. Alternatively, create `DateTime` instances, or convert to unix timestamp values, and compare to the return value of `time()`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Test with timestamp :

```
$timestamp_current_season_expiry = strtotime('2016-07-23');
$timestamp_date = strtotime(date('Y-m-d'));

if( $timestamp_current_season_expiry >= $timestamp_date ) {
    echo "is not expired";
}else{
    echo "expired";
}
```

Answer (score 2):

For starters, you need to add dashes in your call to date():

Change:

```
date("Ymd")
```

To:

```
date("Y-m-d")
```

The original would yield a string of "20160624" instead of "2016-06-24", which would throw off any comparisons.

There's also the future possibility of timezone issues, which you could mitigate by making sure all comparisons are done using UTC:

```
echo $current_season_expiry_utc; // Make sure this is in UTC
if( $current_season_expiry_utc >= gmDate("Y-m-d") ) {
    echo "is not expired";
}else{
    echo "expired";
}
```

... or using timestamps:

```
echo $current_season_expiry_stamp; // Make sure this is a timestamp
if( $current_season_expiry_stamp >= time() ) {
    echo "is not expired";
}else{
    echo "expired";
}
```